# R, ylab not well displayed when plotting in png

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am plotting 2 graphs (one of them is a barplot) in the same png file.

My plot has 2 y axis. My problem is that the label at the second y axis (at the right) is not displayed in my image.

[image]

I thought it was because of my image size. So I change the default value 480 to 600 and it gives me this

[image]

I use axis(4) to put the second y axis at the right.
Strangely, when I do axis(1), it both of my y axis labels are displayed at the left.

Can someone tell me where does this problem come from ?

Answer (score 8):

That's because you have to fix your margins, try `par(mar=c(5,4,4,4))` before your plotting code. And see [this](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html) for an ok description or `par`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730223/second-y-axis-ylabs-location). The function I was lookng for is `mtext()`

Comment: This will write text in the margins, you'd better adjust the margins themselves, the graph you showed us looks bad because `axis(4)` do not have the room it should

Comment: and feel free to accept your answer or mine or tell us what you are missing

Comment: I also think your method is best but mine is too easy to use (It took me few moment to got what I wanted), even if it is enough cramped.