# How to superimpose two ts objects with two different axes with ts.plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, charts, data-visualization, axis

```
library(tseries)
library(readxl)

data = read_excel(.......)

#Create tseries

equity = ts(data$EQUITY, start = c(2015,01,01), end = c(2020,01,01), frequency = 12)
cci = ts(data$CCI, start = c(2015,01,01), end = c(2020,01,01), frequency = 12)

#Plot the two series together

ts.plot(equity, cci, lty = c(1:2))
```

This code returns the following chart: [R Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo0aa.png).

Keeping in mind that I'd like to use the `ts.plot` function since I'm plotting other `tseries` objects and I'm not a fan of how `ggplot2` handles them, **is there a way to add a second axis to the chart and make it so that the two series appear superimposed instead of being far apart like in the linked image?** The desired result would be like in this chart plotted with Python and `matplotlib`: [Python Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVimO.png), possibly with a legend, too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could easily replicate that type of plot with ggplot2 - it will handle the time series just fine if you know how. It is possible in base R too, but will require a bit of work. We can't really show you how to do it unless we have some data to work with though. Could you perhaps edit your question to include the output of `dput(equity)` and `dput(cci)`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plot.ts rather than ts.plot like this.  (See ?legend for other legend position keywords.)

```
z <- ts(cbind(1:10, 110:101))
col <- c("black", "blue")

plot(z[, 1], xlab = "", ylab = "", yaxt = "n", col = col[1])
axis(2, col.axis = col[1])
par(new = TRUE)
plot(z[, 2], xlab = "", ylab = "", yaxt = "n", col = col[2])
axis(4, col.axis = col[2])
legend("top", legend = c("z1", "z2"), lty = 1, 
  col = col, text.col = col)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm! I would add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730223/second-y-axis-ylabs-location) for those who want to add labels to both axes. Thanks again!

Comment: Added a legend.